# What can be done to best preserve the quality of protein when reheating with sides in a microwave?

Tags: meat, microwave, reheating

For a single male the most economical way of preparing food is to cook for multiple days at once and reheating the food in the microwave the next day. This is fine for the most part, but there is one major problem: due to the way microwaves reheat food from the inside out, it tends to dry out the protein (meat/fish/seafood) or change the doneness, which affects the quality of the meal.

What steps can be taken when microwaving the food, preparing it or even during shopping to help preserve the quality of the food? Even if it's just something like "try to buy these forms of protein since they're less dependent on doneness or don't dry out as fast".

Answer (score 5):

Don't blame the microwave. It doesn't cook "inside out"; it just cooks relatively evenly compared to the heat of an oven or hob. But it also cooks quickly, and so you are cooking your food *way* past its previous level of doneness while trying to "reheat" it.

The solution is simple: Microwave *carefully*, at lower power and with more frequent testing for doneness. Don't let it go until it's hissing and bubbling, and give the food frequent rests (this is what microwaving at lower power does) to allow the temperature to equalize throughout. And test, test, test.

Here's a good trick: Take a fork and pierce directly into the thickest part of the food. Leave it there for five seconds or so. Then take it out and press the flat of the tines (the part of the fork that was in the middle) against your lips. You'll be able to get a pretty good feel for the current temperature of the food that way, and how it compares to your preferred serving temperature.

If you don't want to be careful, and just want to zap the stuff until it's boiling, you'll want foods that have been slow-cooked, like stews and pasta sauces. Since those have already been cooked at near-boiling temperatures, you won't do much harm to them.

Incidentally, I should point out that these suggestions apply to everyone, not just males.

Comment: Yep, using your microwave power level is key. I generally do a 60% power for about twice as long as I would normally to warm something up

Comment: In general, stirable foods are easier to reheat in a microwave because you can mix the hot and cold parts part way through. For something like lasagne it's still worth cutting your portion into quarters, and turning each quarter around to get more even cooking.